# Erro ao usar o Gerenciador de Pacotes NuGet no VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, code-first, nuget

Instalei o VS 2017 community 2017 e dá esse erro quando preciso usar o Gerenciador de Pacotes Nuget ?

> ```
> PM> enable-migrations
> enable-migrations : O termo 'enable-migrations' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa 
> operável. Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um caminho tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e tente novamente.
> No linha:1 caractere:1
> + enable-migrations
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (enable-migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você fez a instalação do Entity Framework?

Comment: Sim, o EF estava instalado, porém fiz alguns testes desinstalando o VS 2017 e em seguida voltei para o VS 2015 sem a atualização (Update3) daí sim funcionou com VS 2015, como estou atrasado com datas vou usar a instalação atual do VS 2015 community para andar com o projeto.

Comment: Então, talvez seja uma boa ideia apagar a pergunta.